# Differentiating $V=\frac{t^3}{4}-3t\div5$

Tags: derivatives

Find dV/dt
$$V=\frac{t^3}{4}-3t\div5$$

This is quite a simple question, but after checking the markscheme I am a little bit confused

The mark scheme says the answer is

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{3t^2}{4}-3$$

However the answer I get is (and the answer mathway returns)

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{3t^2}{4}-\frac{3}{5}$$

Am I to assume the markscheme is wrong or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure $V$ shouldn't be:
$$V=\frac{\color{red}{t^3}}{4}-\frac{3t}{5}$$

Comment: Yes, sorry I have fixed it.

Comment: Then the markscheme is wrong, and you are correct.

Comment: Thanks, I know this was obvious, I was just a little bit apprehensive as they are not usually incorrect.

Comment: When you know how to write fractions then why use $\div$ ? :)

Comment: That's how the question was written in the exam.

Comment: Seems like ÷ should have been +

Comment: My guess is that the question had a typo. The divide symbol must have been "+". Then the markscheme answer would make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the result given to you and the "weirdness" in the symbol $÷$, I would say it should have been a $+$, which makes sense since if :

$$V=\frac{t^3}{4} - 3t + 5$$

then, indeed, the derivative would be :

$$V'=\frac{3t^2}{4} - 3$$

In the other case around, you're correct.